# $\int f^2(x)dx=0$ if $\int f(x) x^n=0 $ for all $n=1,2,3,\dots$ (TIFR GS ($2012$))

Tags: real-analysis, integration, proof-verification

Question is to check if  for a continuous function $f: [0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$

$$\int_0^1 f^2(x)dx=0 \text { given that }\int_0^1 f(x) x^n=0  ~\forall ~n=0,1,2,3,\dots$$

I think it is true and I say that because :

Any continuous function on $[0,1]$ can be approximated by polynomials uniformly

i.e., I would have $f_n\rightarrow f$ where each $f_n$ is a polynomial.

Now, Consider $\int_0^1 f(x) f_n(x)dx$, we have

$\int_0^1 f(x) f_n(x)dx= \int_0^1 f(x) (\sum_{i=1}^m a_ix^i)dx=\sum_{i=1}^m a_i(\int_0^1 f(x) x^i)dx$

but then, I have $\int_0^1 f(x) x^n=0$ for all $n=0,1,2,3,\dots $ which would imply

$\int_0^1 f(x) f_n(x)dx= \int_0^1 f(x) (\sum_{i=1}^m a_ix^i)dx=\sum_{i=1}^m a_i(\int_0^1 f(x) x^i)dx=\sum_{i=1}^m a_i .0=0$

Thus, I have $\int_0^1 f(x) f_n(x)dx=0$ for all $n=1,2,3,\dots$

Now I want to say that

$\int_0^1 f^2(x)dx= \int_0^1 f(x)f(x)dx=  \int_0^1 f(x)(\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}f_n(x))dx=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}(\int_0^1 f(x)f_n(x)dx)=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} (0)=0$

Thus, I would say $\int_0^1 f^2(x)dx=0$

I would be thankful if some one can check what i have done is technically flawless (if there is any please help me to repair it).

Thank you.

P.S : I would request all of you to just give me hints and please do not post an answer as this is just a proof verification.

Comment: Stating that the convergence is uniform, is essential.

Comment: What is your justification for changing the order of the integral and the limit?

Comment: yes yes... I should not have missed to write that uniform convergence part

Comment: As the convergence is uniform i can change the order of integral and limit...

Comment: Looks quite good. One thing I'm worrying about is that the power $x^n, n=0,$ is excluded from the list of orthogonality relations. Is uniform approximation by a polynomial still possible, if the polynomials are constrained to have zero constant term?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen : As always, my question had a typo... $n=0$ is also included... :) Thank you  :)

Comment: Ahh! Ok! I was trying to figure out a way of showing that the relation with $n=0$ might be a consequence of the other relations, but now I can relax :-)

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen : Yes, you can relax :) I can sleep happily now... (It is already 2:00 AM now in my place).. :)